# Hit hundreds of requests concurrently using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, afnetworking, alamofire

I need to hit hundreds of requests concurrently to upload files. I am using AFNetworking and I simply call a method from for loop. But it gives me internal server error in some of the files. There is nothing on Server Side. This process is successfully executed from Web.

Here is my code :

```
for (UIImage *img in imgages) {
        [self uploadImage:img];
      }


-(void) uploadImage:(UIImage *)image
{



    //    NSDictionary *someData=@{x:x }
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:someData
                                                       options:0

                                                         error:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"xyz.com"] parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonData name:@"abc"];

        if (imgData) {

            [formData appendPartWithFormData:imgData name:@"file"];

        }
    } error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

     NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;

   manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    uploadTask = [manager
                  uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                  progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                  }];

    [uploadTask resume];

}
```

What would be the best way to implement above functionality ?

Comment: What's the exact error you receive?  iOS has a per-host concurrent request limit, but if that's what you are experiencing, you would be getting timeouts from excessive requests.

Comment: try using `dispatch_apply` instead of fo-loop

Comment: @Vikas Kindly accept the answer if its working

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code for concurrently upload files.

```
 -(id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self) {
    backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.bgqueue", NULL);

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.Demo-Upload"];
        sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10;
         manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    });
}
return self;
}

- (void)processFiles{
    for (UIImage *img in imgages) {
         dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
             [self uploadImage:img];
         });
    }
}


-(void) uploadImage:(UIImage *)image
{
     // Prepare a temporary file to store the multipart request prior to sending it to the server due to an alleged
     // bug in NSURLSessionTask.
     NSString* tmpFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
     NSURL* tmpFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFilename]];

     // Create a multipart form request.
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"xyz.com"] parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:jsonData name:@"abc"];

       if (imgData) {
          [formData appendPartWithFormData:imgData name:@"file"];
       }
     } error:nil];

     // Dump multipart request into the temporary file.
    [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMultipartFormRequest:request
                                          writingStreamContentsToFile:tmpFileUrl
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
          // Once the multipart form is serialized into a temporary file, we can initialize
          // the actual HTTP request using session manager.


          // Here note that we are submitting the initial multipart request. We are, however,
          // forcing the body stream to be read from the temporary file.

           self.uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                fromFile:tmpFileUrl
                                progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
                                            {
                                                NSLog(@"Progress… %f", uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);
                                            }
                                completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error)
                                           {
                                               // Cleanup: remove temporary file.
                                               [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:tmpFileUrl error:nil];

                                               // Do something with the result.
                                               if (error)
                                               {
                                                 //Print Error
                                               } else
                                               {
                                                   //Print responseObject
                                               }
                                           }];
         // Start the file upload.
         [self.uploadTask resume];
    }];
}
```

Above function will continue upload images in when app goes to background. So, this will not give you internal server error or any timeout error.

Hope it will help you. And if you have any doubt regarding above code then please feel free to ask.